# Characterize Powersets among CPOs

Tags: category-theory, order-theory, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

Powersets can be seen as complete atomic boolean algebras.

> Is it possible to characterize **complete atomic boolean algebras** ([CABA](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/complete+Boolean+algebra)) among **complete partial orders** ([CPO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_partial_order))?

For example, it is possible to characterize **complete [Heyting Algebras](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Heyting+algebra)** as **complete  posets** where $$a \wedge \bigvee a_i = \bigvee a \wedge a_i.$$

In this sense a complete boolen algebra is just a complete partial order with an exactness property, the *infinitary distributivity law*.

My guess, in fact my hope, is that CABAs correspond to **complete atomic regular posets**. By regular I mean that the poset is a [regular category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/regular+category).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "characterize" ? Their definition is entirely in terms of order-theoretic notions so I think you'll have to be more precise

Comment: As I say in the question, complete HAs can be characterized as complete and cartesian closed poset. I am looking for a similar characterization that only involves [property-like structure](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stuff,+structure,+property).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/atom#generalization_and_categorification) nlab page,

> Powersets are precisely atomic CPOs.

The definition of atom and atomic is a bit different from the one expected by lattice theorists. Traslating from mine terminology to theirs,   *atomic* means that **there is a join-dense subset of completely join-irreducible elements**.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming by complete you mean in the categorical sense, i.e. you want limit-closure (i.e. meet-closure in the poset case), I suppose that your complete boolean algebras should be the same as complete [star-autonomous categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/star-autonomous+category) where the monoidal product is the cartesian one.

In these categories you have an involution operator (the $*$ in star-autonomous) which plays the role of the negation and indeed you have, in the posetal case, de morgan laws and the middle excluded.

**Edit**: I see thatthe OP was looking for a property-like definition, hence the following addendum.
As shown in the link above $*$-autonomous categories admit a definition in a almost-property like way (as long as we are considering just cartesian closed category) using the dualizing object $(\bot)$ instead of the involution functor $(*)$.

This is an *almost* property like, as opposed to property like, because we require the object $\bot$ to satisfy the condition

> the morphism $A \to ((A \multimap \bot) \multimap \bot)$ to be an isomorphism

the problem is that in a general category this object would be an additional structure on the category.

**But** if our cartesian closed category, $*$-auotnomous, is a poset $\bot$ is necessarily the bottom element, i.e. the minimum.

To see that one can observe that if $ ((A \multimap \bot) \multimap \bot) \leq A$, which is the poset-version of the property above, since obviously $\bot \leq ((A \multimap \bot) \multimap \bot)$ it follows that $\bot \leq A$.

From this it follows that in a star-autonomous (cartesian) poset the *global dualizing object* must be the minimum of the poset.

So a star-autonomous-poset is nothing but a cartesian-closed-posetal category with a minimum $\bot$ that satisfies the property 
$$((A \multimap \bot) \multimap \bot \leq A$$

This should provide a property-like definition as you wished....or at least I hope so :-D

Comment: I am sorry to say that this is not the kind of answer I am looking for. In fact the $*$ operator is an additional structure, and not a property.

In particular the operator $\neg$ is perfectly definable in a complete  lattice as $\neg a := \bigvee_{d : d \wedge a = \bot} d$. Thus one could state the property of "having the $\neg$ operator" as an exactness property. What I really want to know is if this exactness property coincides with a very classical one, such as regularity, or being Heyting or whatever.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti I've made a little addendum that should address your concerns. Let me know if it's ok.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect.